# <span/> field with HTML enter gives different width/margin than withouth HTML enter

Tags: input, width, margin, html

The following code:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">Selectiedatum</span>
<input type="text" value="30-06-2013" style="width:100px;text-align: right;" />
```

Gives a different output than:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">Selectiedatum</span><input type="text" value="30-06-2013" style="width:100px;text-align: right;" />
```

Yes, the only difference is a HTML enter...

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Et4WZ/

The problem is that this code is created by ASP.net; I can't just simply add or remove a HTML enter.

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any amount of whitespace is rendered as a single space when it's between two inline elements.

Comment: Thanks Blender, Your're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender was right.

I fixed it by adding a span field with 1 whitespace:

```
<span> </span>
```

So:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">Selectiedatum</span><span> </span><input type="text" value="30-06-2013" style="width:100px;text-align: right;" />
```